# What is this restricted sum of multinomial coefficients?

Tags: co.combinatorics

It is relatively easy to show that
$$
\sum_{a_1 + \cdots + a_k=\ell} \binom{\ell}{a_1,\ldots,a_k} = k^\ell
$$
where $\binom{\ell}{a_1, \ldots, a_k} = \frac{\ell!}{a_1!\cdots a_k!}$. What can be said if we want to compute the restricted sum
$$
s(\ell,k) = \sum_{a_1 + \cdots + a_k=\ell} \binom{\ell}{a_1,\ldots,a_k}
$$
where we now restrict the summation to those $a_k$ which are odd? At the least, of course, we need that $\ell \geq k$ and that $\ell \equiv k \pmod 2$. Is this sum known in the literature?

The simplest case of $s(2k,2) = 2^{2k-1}$ can be easily verified, but I believe that this is an anomoly based on the fact that these are (secretly) binomial coefficients.

This arises in computing the coefficients of the power series of $\big(\sin(x)\big)^k$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\binom{\ell}{a_1,\dots,a_k}$ is the coefficient of $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_k^{a_k}$ in the expansion of
$$(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell}.$$
The sum of all these coefficients is obtained by substituting $x_1=\dots=x_k=1$.

To eliminate even $a_1$, we can consider the expansion of 
$$\frac{1}{2}(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell} - \frac{1}{2}(-x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell}.$$

Continuing this way, we eventually get
$$s(\ell,k) = \frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{t_1,\dots,t_k=0}^1 (-1)^{t_1+\dots+t_k} ((-1)^{t_1}+\cdots+(-1)^{t_k})^{\ell}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{z=0}^k \binom{k}{z} (-1)^z (k-2z)^{\ell}.$$

P.S. This formula resembles one for Stirling number of the second kind (formula (10) at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html)) but not quite.

Comment: Combinatorial interpretation: number of of walks of length $l$ joining two antipodal points in the $k$-dimensional cube.

Comment: This is the formula that you get by expanding 
$$\sinh^k z = \left( e^z - e^{-z}\over 2\right)^k$$
by the binomial theorem. These numbers are essentially central factorial numbers.


Comment: Sorry for my delayed comment. I am trying to understand the answer. It is mentioned that to eliminate even $a_1$  we consider the expansion $\frac{1}{2}(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell} - \frac{1}{2}(-x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell}.$ I do not catch the intuition. Could you please provide some more details?

Comment: @Thoth: This is how we compute the [odd part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Even%E2%80%93odd_decomposition) of a function with respect to $x_1$.

Comment: Thanks I didn;t know that. So the odd part of $f(x_1, \dots, x_k) = (x_1 + \dots, x_k)^l$ is $f_o(x_1, \dots, x_k) = \frac{1}{2} (f(x_1, \dots, x_k)  - f(-x_1, \dots, -x_k))$ ? I am trying to use this with the multinomial expansion $f(x_1, \dots, x_k) = \sum_{a_1 + \cdots + a_k=\ell} \binom{\ell}{a_1,\ldots,a_k} \prod_{i=1}^{k} x_i^{a_i}$ to get the first line of $s(l, k)$ but I could not reproduce your result. Could you please provide some intermediate step? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Actually applying multinomial expansion I am getting $f_o(x_1, \dots,x_k) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{a_1 + \cdots + a_k=\ell} \binom{\ell}{a_1,\ldots,a_k} (1 - \prod_{i=1}^{k} (-1)^{a_i} \right)$. In addition, the superscripts $t_i$ in your answer are different from $a_i$?

Comment: @Thoth: No, you need to deal with one variable at a time. First, it's $\frac{1}{2}\big((x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell} - (-x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell}\big)$, then it's $$\frac{1}{4}\big((x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell} - (-x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell} - (x_1 - x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell} + (-x_1 - x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell}\big),$$ etc. Eventually you'll arrive at the formula with $2^k$ terms given in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, I can not reproduce the result. I see the comment of @Gjergji Zaimi [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248141/sum-of-multinomial-coefficients-even-distribution?rq=1) but not intermediate steps are give when starting from $\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{\varepsilon_i=\pm 1}(\varepsilon_1x_1+\cdots+\varepsilon_k x_k)^r$. Could you please provide these intermediate steps in your answer to fully understand the procedure?

Comment: @Thoth: Gjergji's formula is the same as the first one for $s(\ell,k)$ in my answer. To arrive at the second formula, just group summands with the same value of the expression in parentheses. Namely, if there are $z$ minus-ones and $(k-z)$ plus-ones, then this value is $k-2z$. The number of such summands equals $\binom{k}{z}$, which is the number of ways to pick $z$ positions for minus-ones out of $k$ positions.

Comment: First, I am trying to see the relation of $$\frac{1}{4}\big((x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell} - (-x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell} - (x_1 - x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell} + (-x_1 - x_2 + \dots + x_k)^{\ell}\big),$$ with $$\frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{t_1,\dots,t_k=0}^1 (-1)^{t_1+\dots+t_k} ((-1)^{t_1}+\cdots+(-1)^{t_k})^{\ell}.$$ In the second one there are exponents inside the $l$-th power that makes it hard to understand. In addition, the maximum value of $t_1,\dots,t_k$ in $\sum_{t_1,\dots,t_k=0}^1$ is $l$ instead of $1$? I have not have the necessary experience as it seems.

Comment: Second, the relation of $$\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{\varepsilon_i=\pm 1}(\varepsilon_1x_1+\cdots+\varepsilon_k x_k)^r$$ with $$\frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{t_1,\dots,t_k=0}^1 (-1)^{t_1+\dots+t_k} ((-1)^{t_1}+\cdots+(-1)^{t_k})^{\ell}$$ is not obvious to me right now from what I am aware.

Comment: @Thoth: We have $\epsilon_i = (-1)^{t_i}$ for all $i$, and in the current settings $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_k=1$.

Comment: hanks for the comment. I think now I understand the first part in $S(l,k)$. Now I am trying to understand is the second part. In one of you comments above you mention that there are $\binom{k}{z}$ summands that equals to $k-2z$. What I do not understand is how this information is used to construct $\sum_{z=0}^k \binom{k}{z} (-1)^z (k-2z)^{\ell}$. Can you please provide some details on the intuition to construct it? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Thoth: I said that $k-2z$ is the value for the expression in parentheses. The corresponding summand value is $(-1)^z(k-2z)^\ell$, and there are $\binom{k}{z}$ such summands for each value of $z$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thanks again for the comment. I think now that I understand completely all the part. Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like (but needs checking that)
$$ \sum \frac{1}{\ell!} s(\ell,k) z^\ell t^k = \exp(t \sinh(z)). $$
That could probably be used to find other formulas, recurrences, etc.

ADDED:
http://oeis.org/A136630  OEIS sequence A136630 is about these numbers.

Comment: This probably comes back full circle to the original proposer's motivating problem of computing the coefficients of $\sin^k(x)$ (which are the same as the $\sinh^k(x)$ coefficients up to sign).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach the original problem is to recall the formula:
$$\cos(y)^k = \frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}\cos((k-2j)y).$$
Plugging in $y=\frac{\pi}{2} - x$ would give an expansion for $\sin(x)^k$. 
I suspect eventually it would lead to the same formula that I gave in the previous answer.