# Sum of multinomial coefficients (even distribution)

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis

By multinomial expansion formula, we know that $$ \sum_{p_1 + \cdots + p_k = r} \binom{r}{p_1,\ldots,p_k} = k^r, $$ where the multinomial coefficient is defined by $ \binom{r}{p_1, \ldots, p_k} := \frac{r!}{p_1!\cdots p_k!}$. Here is my question:

How can we find the sum $$ \sum_{p_1 + \cdots + p_k=r} \binom{r}{p_1,\ldots,p_k} $$ with the restriction that all $ p_j $'s are even?  This sum shows up in some multiple commutators of Hilbert space operators. Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you take the averaged sum over all choices of signs $$\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{\varepsilon_i=\pm 1}(\varepsilon_1x_1+\cdots+\varepsilon_k x_k)^r$$ we see that only the terms with even exponents survive. If we place all $x_i=1$ we get the quantity that you are interested in. This is more explicitly equal to
$$\frac{1}{2^k}\left(\sum_{m=0}^k \binom{k}{m}(k-2m)^r\right).$$

Comment: The sum is the coefficient of $x^r/r!$ in $\cosh^k x$.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73613/what-is-this-restricted-sum-of-multinomial-coefficients

Comment: Thanks Gjergji! Thanks a lot for your quick responses!  So, (basically) the same method has been applied to the case when all $p_j$'s are odd in Max's post. Great! :-)

Answer (score 3):

> If you take the averaged sum over all choices of signs $$\frac{1}{2^k}
> \sum_{\varepsilon_i = \pm 1} (\varepsilon_1x_1 + \cdots +
> \varepsilon_kx_k)^r$$ we see that only the terms with even exponents
>   survive. If we place all $x_i=1$ we get the quantity that you are
>   interested in. This is more explicitly equal to $$ \frac{1}{2^k}
> \left( \sum_{m=0}^k {k \choose m} (k-2m)^r \right).$$

– Gjergji Zaimi, Aug 24 at 0:45

> The sum is the coefficient of $x^r/r!$ in $\cosh^kx$.

– Ira Gessel, Aug 24 at 3:53

> See also [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73613/...](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73613/what-is-this-restricted-sum-of-multinomial-coefficients)

– Max Alekseyev Aug 24 at 9:38

Comment: I'm posting the comments as a community wiki answer so that this question can be "answered" without me gaining any unearned rep.

Comment: ... per the best answer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins